# Change JNDI Provider Dynamically

Tags: java, spring, jms, jndi, hornetq

I have two HornetQ (2.2.14) standalone servers (live-backup servers) on the same machine; Consider this scenario:

1. *Live server* crashed, *Backup server* is now live.
2. *Client A* (doesn't know Live server crashed) want connect to Live server (it should look up its *Connection Factory* with *Live servers JNDI provider*).
3. Client A can't find Live servers JNDI provider, **so it should connect to Backup server (it should look up its Connection Factory with *Backup servers JNDI provider*).**

**How can i change JNDI provider (change URL) *dynamically* for Client A? Is there any way for JNDI failover?**

I have a spring integrated application and it's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Default JndiTemplate -->
        <bean id="defaultJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
            <property name="environment">
                <props>
                    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
                    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

 <!-- Backup JndiTemplate -->
        <bean id="backupJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
            <property name="environment">
                <props>
                    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
                    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:2099</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

    <!-- Destinations -->
    <bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="defaultJndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="/queue/exampleQueue" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ConnectionFactories -->
    <bean id="defaultConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="defaultJndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JMS Template -->
    <bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="defaultConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Message Producer -->
    <bean name="messageSender" class="messaging.producer.MessageSender">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
        <property name="destination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    </bean>
```

**Update:**
I can handle looking up the connection factory from current live serrver in my application in this way:
For each message,

1. Check available JNDI provider (from current live server)
2. look up the connection factory
3. send message

Something like this (it's from my *MessageSender* class):

```
    //init initialContexts for live and backup servers
    public init() throws NamingException, CommunicationException
        {
            Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
            initialContext_live = new InitialContext(environment);

            environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:2099");
            initialContext_backup = new InitialContext(environment);

            jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();

        }
        //Sending message to toQueue
        public void send(final AbstractMessage message, String toQueue) throws NamingException 
        {
            Destination destination;
            try
            {
                connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext_live.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
                jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                destination = (Destination) initialContext_live.lookup(toQueue);
                System.out.print("[to-live]-");
            }
            catch(Exception e) //live server is down
            {
                connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext_backup.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
                jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                destination = (Destination) initialContext_backup.lookup(toQueue);
                System.out.print("[to-backup]-");
            }
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() 
            {
                @Override
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException 
                {
                    ObjectMessage objMessage = session.createObjectMessage(message);
                    return objMessage;
                }
            });
            System.out.println("[MessageSender] Message sent.");
        }
```

But it's **very** time consuming (about one message in two seconds)!!!

Answer (score 0):

what i found here are two things

first you set one global flag and put if else conditions

```
flag=true;
if(flag){
 try
        {
            connectionFactory =      (ConnectionFactory)initialContext_live.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
            jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            destination = (Destination) initialContext_live.lookup(toQueue);
            System.out.print("[to-live]-");
        }
}else{
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext_backup.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
            jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            destination = (Destination) initialContext_backup.lookup(toQueue);
            System.out.print("[to-backup]-");
}
        catch(Exception e) //live server is down
        {
flag=false;
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext_backup.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
            jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            destination = (Destination) initialContext_backup.lookup(toQueue);
            System.out.print("[to-backup]-");
        }
```

so here it will not check the code for live server if somehow connection lost in between it will directly connect to backup server

and if your live server is up you can set flag to true.

and second thing in catch block instead of exception declare it for specific exception. it  also affect performance.

Comment: Thanks, it's better! But i wonder if there is a way for JNDI failover!

Comment: no it will work what we need to do once we come to know live server is up we need to set flag true.